Sum of iid Random Variables is still iid
I have found the following Proposition:
Let $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ be a familiy of iid uniformly distributed random variables on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}$ and define $\vec{\theta} = A \vec{\varphi}$. Then $\vec{\theta}$ is a family of iid random variables distributed uniformly on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $A$ has full rank.
The proof in the literature is basically the following for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^m$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle k, \vec{\theta} \rangle}) = \mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle A^T k, \vec{\varphi} \rangle}) = \delta_{A^T k, 0}
\end{align*}
My interpretation of this is:
For any $k \neq 0$, the sum $\langle k , \vec{\varphi} \rangle$ is uniformly distributed on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ (I didn't yet think of a proof, but it seems intuitively true. Additionally, it does not hold for RVs with a non-uniform distribution). Thus, the $\theta_j$ are uniformly distributed if $A$ does not have a $0$-row. Furthermore, if $\vec{\theta}$ is independent, we have for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}^n$
\begin{align} \label{eq: def ind}
\mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle k , \vec{\theta} \rangle}) = \prod_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}(e^{i k_j \theta_j})
\end{align}
Can we turn this into and if and only if? That means, do we have this formula for all $k$ if and only if the family $\vec{\theta}$ is independent?
Then, using $\mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle k, \vec{\theta} \rangle}) = \mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle A^T k, \vec{\varphi} \rangle})$ and $\mathbb{E}(e^{i \varphi_j})=0$, we would obtain
\begin{align}
\vec{\theta} \text{ independent } \iff \mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle k, \vec{\theta} \rangle}) = \delta_{k,0} \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}^m \iff \mathbb{E} (e^{i \langle A^T k, \vec{\varphi} \rangle}) = \delta_{k,0} \text{ for all } k \in \mathbb{Z}^m \iff \text{ker}(A^T) = \{0\}
\end{align}
Do we have the if and only if version of the second equation? And furthermore, can we generalize this to other families of random variables? To me it seems that we need uniform distribution in order to obtain the identically distributed part, but maybe there is some other family of RVs such that a similar statement holds...?
